# DNS Server usage at Linode.com

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-registration, linode

Until now i used old fasioned LAMP webhosting for 3 websites. I have 1 domain for each of the websites.

Yesterday i bought myself a linode and to my surprise linode has DNS servers available for its users. I did not know this when i bought it.

Now, I WAS going to cancel the webhosting contract at my old provider but keep the 3 domains there and point the domains to my linode IP.

But now that i found out i can use linodes DNS servers, does this mean i can cancel my subscripton at my old provider? In other words, can i transfer my domains to linode? 
I think i'm getting confused because of the following phrase in linode help:

> To get started with our DNS Manager, make sure your domain name is set to use our DNS servers. You will need to use your domain name registrar's interface for setting the name servers for your domain to the following entries:

How do i point my domain to linode dns servers, and what's the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your domains are registered through that ISP, they are not expensive for just the domains, and their DNS servers are stable, reliable and offer all the control you need, then there is probably little or no benefit to you.

If your domains are registered through another registrar (or you move them to one) then you are relying on one less company (the registrar and linode, not registrar+other+linode).

You might also find that the linode feature allows you greater control than you currently have, though you might also find the opposite it true so do check before moving your domains over if you do.

If you change to using linode's DNS servers (or any others) make sure your domains are completely and correctly configured on the new DNS servers *before* switching the name-server settings at your registrar.

Comment: So in my current case the webhosting provider is both registrar and dns server host. But linode is only a dns server host? So i cant move my domain registration to linode?

So if i want to move my domains away from the current place i need to find another registrar first and then choose to either use that registrars dns servers or linodes dns servers?

Comment: Exactly. Any registrar will accept a transfer of this sort, though be careful to check your current ISPs smallprint as some have nasty transfer-out fees for domain names.

Answer (score 3):

Linode actually have an [IRC channel](http://www.linode.com/irc/) open and they usually have one of their very qualified technicians monitoring the channel. They also provide forums for asking questions in addition to a [wealth of articles](http://www.linode.com/community/). I find the Linode community very helpful and I've been using Linode for the last 3 years. Personally I have my own DNS servers running (one on Linode and one using a UK provider) for control and redundancy so I don't know how to use Linode's DNS service (which wasn't around when I first started using Linode).

Comment: While your comment about the linode community was very valuable, you didn't actually answer the question.